# What user settings to give in VS Code for formatting/linting when using ESLint and Prettier? (Read Description)

Tags: javascript, eslint, visual-studio-code, prettier

I watched this video,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIvjKId9m2c

And read this article,
https://medium.com/appstud/eslint-and-prettier-working-on-visual-studio-code-with-create-react-app-32dfef4b029c

Why in both examples we have to do this in user.settings.json,

```
“[javascript]”: {
 “editor.formatOnSave”: false,
},
“prettier.disableLanguages”: [
 “js”
]
```

Why to disable format on save for JS files? Wouldn’t it be tiresome to manually format every time?
And disabling prettier for JS seems to defeat the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

1. VS Code has an inbuilt formatter which takes care of basic linting
   out of the box. You do not even need ESlint or Prettier for that to
   work. But if you have installed ESLint plugin, it would be better to
   rely on its formatter. Hence we disable the built-in format on save
   that comes with vscode.
2. If you have installed `eslint-plugin-prettier` and added this
   setting `"extends": ["react-app", "plugin:prettier/recommended"]`,
   the you already have prettier's rules included within the eslint.
   Hence you do not need a separate prettier plugin for javascript. But
   you may need it for other files (`css`, `md`). Hence its disabled
   just for javascript.

Comment: About the answer for point #1, wouldn't it be better to do ""javascript.format.enable": false" in VSCode user settings? This would make sure that the default formatter doesn't interfere. This way I don't have to disable the formatOnSave option and thus make things easier as I don't have to manually format.

Comment: Yes, you should also be having the rule `""javascript.format.enable": false"`. But apparently that is not sufficient to prevent default auto saver from interfering. You need the `“editor.formatOnSave”: false` as well.  You can try it and check.